# Access to Excel Export Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, export, ms-access-2010

I have a `DoCmd` to export a query into an Excel file but when I go to open the Excel file I get an error message stating, "Excel cannot open because the file format and extension is not valid." What can be causing this to happen when I export the file and attempt to open it?

```vb
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "qryComplete", "C:\Users\Downloads\Reports\Report_Name " & Format(Date, "mmddyy") & ".xlsx", True
```

Comment: @HansUp .. Something so simple, that was exactly it. I tried Excel12 but I had got the same error which is why I tried Excel9. Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: Understandable.  Personally, I think the *SpreadsheetType* thing is unnecessarily challenging to sort out.  In the Access 2010 *AcSpreadSheetType Enumeration* help topic, neither `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` nor `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` is even listed.  Oops!  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9` for the *SpreadsheetType* option, use `.xls` as the file extension.

If you want `.xlsx` as the file extension, use `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` for *SpreadsheetType*.

The error happens because `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9` and `.xlsx` is not a valid combination.